# Error adding AdMob with Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with Xamarin Visual Studio, specifically with the AdMob banner. How do I correctly add the AdMob banner?

I downloaded the components (Google Play Services - Ads) successfully.

Here is my code:

### MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
//using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Android;

namespace App7
{
    [Activity(Label = "App7", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        AdView mAdView;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            ShowAdsBanner();
        }

        void ShowAdsBanner()
        {
            mAdView = FindViewById<AdView>(Resource.Id.adViewResult);
            var adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            // Start loading the ad.
            mAdView.LoadAd(adRequest);

        }
    }


}
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App7.App7" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="App7">
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

### Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Hello" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="my id here " />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have error in main.xml

Screenshot of the errors
[image: the error]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making sure that all of your components are updated, specifically the v7.appcompat component as that seems to be conflicting with the attributes.

If that doesn't work try deleting the packages and redownloading them.

I have a project currently set up with both of those components and those two attributes don't throw errors when I build. Best of Luck!